# How to Simplify this Fourier Series Summation?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, fourier-series

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k = \infty} \frac{ik}{|k|(k^2+\lambda)}e^{i2\pi kx}$$

How to simplify this Fourier expansion?

Comment: what is the $k=0$ term?

Comment: maybe useful to you but you have $\frac{k}{|k|} = \mathrm{sgn}(k)$ - thus you can split the summation and reindex. Handling the $k=0$ as above stated.

Comment: @user721481 you can answer modulo k =0 term. Or you can take the zero term as $1/\lambda$